# Is there anyway that we can check the details of regions and zones in GRS replication

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created a storage account in india and used GRS replication and want to know how many times my data will be replicated and information about replication pattern ( whether i will be able to see all the datacenters details ) . Is there anyway that we can check the details of regions and zones in GRS replication . can someone please provide some pointers

Comment: you have all information in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#redundancy-in-a-secondary-region

Comment: What details do you want to know, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned in the comments, your data will be replicated six times when you use `GRS`, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#redundancy-in-a-secondary-region):

[image]

In addition, you can refer to [Azure Paired Regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-availability-paired-regions), it explains the pairing
relationship between regions:

[image]